# mosquitto_sub "connection refused" on Arch Linux

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi, mosquitto, linux

So I installed `mosquitto` and `mosquitto-client` on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Jessie through `apt-get` as well as `mosquitto` on another Pi running Arch Linux through `pacman`. On Arch the client utils do not need to be installed separately.

Testing simple subscription/publishing on Raspbian worked out of the box.

```
mosquitto_sub –d –t blub
mosquitto_pub –d –t blub –m “test”
```

Publishing from the Arch box works as well:

```
mosquitto_pub -h <IP-Raspbian> -t blub -m "test"
```

Subscribing a topic on the Arch system however gets me just:

```
mosquitto_sub –d –t blub
Error: Connection refused
```

Now that is pretty generic. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out there is no broker running on the Arch system whereas installing `mosquitto` on Raspbian automatically starts it. Simply enable and start the broker.

Start the systemd service.

```
systemctl start mosquitto
```

Enable the systemd service to run on boot.

```
systemctl enable mosquitto
```